# Cannot mock admin.firestore() during unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, sinon, firebase-admin

I am reading [how to mock google cloud functions for firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) and have issues of properly mocking the following code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var db = admin.firestore();
```

The example in the link uses the following code to mock `initializeApp` which does work

```
admin = require('firebase-admin');
adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');
```

Now admin.firestore is defined in firebase-namespace.js as following:

```
Object.defineProperty(FirebaseNamespace.prototype, "firestore", {
    get: function () {
        var ns = this;
        var fn = function (app) {
            return ns.ensureApp(app).firestore();
        };
        return Object.assign(fn, require('@google-cloud/firestore'));
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

I've tried various things to stub this but I fail

1. Results in `firestore is not a function`:

   ```
       Object.defineProperty(admin, "firestore", {
           get: function () {
               return 32;
           }
       });
   ```
2. Does not mock firestore() at all and calls the original function which fails hard:

   ```
       sinon.stub(admin, 'firestore').returns({get() { }});
   ```
3. TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property get

   ```
      firestoreStub = sinon.stub(admin.firestore, 'get').callsFake(function () {return {data:"Foo"}});
   ```

I lack understanding what `admin.firebase()` actually is. It does not look like it is a property because AFAI when I mock a getter of a property, I would call `admin.firebase` and not a function `admin.firebase()`. But it is also not mockable via a function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That really took me too long.

To be able to mock the `admin.firebase()` the getter function of the property should actually *return a function*.

My initial assumption was that `firebase()` is a function, which it was not. Then by looking at the implementation I understood that this is a property with a custom getter. However I tried to return some json data block via the getter.

I initially failed to understand that `admin.firestore` is indeed a property but I was missing the key on why I have to call the property as a function, which is typically not needed on the property itself.

After getting to the point I understood that the getter of the property actually returned a function and that the `admin.firebase()` can be read like

```
var method = admin.firebase; // calling the property getter function
method(); // assuming the getter returned a function object
```

So for my future self ;) this does the trick:

```
sinon.stub(admin, 'firestore')
   .get(function() { 
       return function() { 
           return "data";
       }
   });
```

Originally I was trying to do

`sinon.stub(admin, 'firestore').get( function () { return "data"; } );` which failed because the `admin.firestore()` ultimately yielded in `"data"()`, which made no sense.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, Samuel. I'm about to figure out how to mock firestore queries too wish me luck

Comment: @KyleHotchkiss Good luck :) . I extracted as much js code to external modules and tested them with mocha and sinon as possible. The remaining things in my scenario were still over 100 lines of mock code of firestore functions because my cloud function would read various documents and then create various documents in a transaction, mocking the entire nested promises with different return values with chai etc was a pain in the nether regions.

Comment: I tried to implement your stub, for the following code: `const users = await firestore.collection('users').get();`, like this: `const firestoreStub = sinon.stub();
            Object.defineProperty(admin, 'firestore', {
                get: () => {
                    return {
                        collection: (path) => Promise.resolve({mocka: 'user'})
                    }
                }
            });`, but no help. Any idea how to?

Comment: @DauleDK not really, I suggest making a new post where this can be better be read and link both so others and I can look at it. Also probably relevant: Between now and my post firestore has gone 1.0 and has changed their API, I haven't yet had the time to adopt the new API in my code.

Comment: @Samuel good point, I created one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800384/mocking-admin-firestore-collection-get

Comment: Be aware that if you do this kind of stubbing, you'll break functionality as: `test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot()`.