# Mocking admin.firestore().collection().get()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Related to this [question][1], I am trying to mock firestore when doing unit tests.

The code I am trying to mock looks like this:

```
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const users = await firestore.collection('users').get();
```

And my attempt to mock it looks like this:

```
const firestoreStub = sinon.stub();
Object.defineProperty(admin, 'firestore', {
  get: () => {
    return {
      collection: (path) => Promise.resolve({mocka: 'user'})
    }
  }
});
```

However it does not work.

I have created a repo (a clone of the official functions repo), to give the entire example [here](https://github.com/21RISK/functions-samples) if it helps.

Comment: In your code example `firestore`is a function of `admin` but you are trying to define it as a property.  Define a function or mock on your mocked `admin` object which returns your mocked `firestore`.

Comment: Hi @DauleDK, would you mind posting your solution as an answer below? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

With the help from Mark, I got this working:

```
sinon.stub(admin, 'firestore')
        .get(() => {
            return function() {
                return {
                    collection: (path) => {
                        return {
                            get: () => [{user: 'mock-user-1'}, {user: 'mock-user-2'}]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

It looks crazy - so if anyone knows a better solution, let me know!